# Comparing Percent Changes

Tags: percentage

I want to present information in the "most unbiased" manner possible:

- State XYZ increased GDP by 5.0 % last year
- The US increased GDP by 1.0 % last year

Is there any (statistical?) bias in the statement:

"State XYZ grew 4.0x faster than the US."

Thank You

Comment: Well, it's wrong. 5/1 = 5. Other than that, discussion about bias requires one or more of (1) true or at least better values, so that we can (try to) quantify bias (2) discussion of sources of error. If by bias, you mean (political or other) partiality, that's important, but something different.

Comment: I think this is a "how (not) to lie with statistics" issue rather than an estimator bias one.